# How to loop over and access various elements in an array that is both multidimentional and associative? PHP, either JSON or XML

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'm retrieving bibliographic data via an API (zotero.org), and it is similar to the sample at the bottom (just way more convoluted - sample is typed).

I want to retrieve one or more records and display certain values on the page. For example, I would like to loop through each top level record and print the data in a nicely formated citation. Ignoring the proper bib styles for the moment, let's say I want to just print out the following for each record returned:

*author1 name, author2 name, article title, publication title, key*

This doesn't match the code, because I've clearly been referencing the key value pairs incorrectly and will just make a mess of it.

The following is laid out like the data if I request JSON format, though I can request XML data instead. I'm not picky; I've tried using each with no luck.

```
[
  {
    "key": "123456",
    "state": 100,
    "data": {
      "articleTitle": "Wombat coprogenetics: enumerating a common wombat population by microsatellite analysis of faecal DNA",
      "authors": [
        {
          "firstName": "Sam C.",
          "lastName": "Smith"
        },
        {
          "firstName": "Maxine P.",
          "lastName": "Jones"
        }
      ],
      "pubTitle": "Australian Journal of Zoology",
      "tags": [
         {
          "tag": "scary"
        },
        {
          "tag": "secret rulers of the world"
        }
      ]
   }
 },
 {
   "key": "001122",
   "state": 100,
   "data": {
     "articleTitle": "WOMBAT and WOMBAT-PK: Bioactivity Databases for Lead and Drug Discovery",
     "authors": [
        {
          "firstName": "Marius",
          "lastName": "Damstra"
        }
      ],
      "pubTitle": "Chemical Biology: From Small Molecules to Systems Biology",
      "tags": [
        {
          "tag": "Wrong Wombat"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

If there is a mistake in brackets, commas, etc. it is just a typo in my example and not the cause of my issue.

Comment: Scrowler, thank you for the edits! I will pay proper attention next time. :)

Comment: You are right, of course. Now don't you feel all warm and fuzzy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[decode your json](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) as array and iterate it as any array as flowing:

```
$json_decoded= json_decode($json,true);

$tab="\t";

foreach ($json_decoded as $key => $val) {
    echo "Article ".$val["key"]."\n" ;
    echo $tab."Authors :\n";
    foreach ($val["data"]["authors"] as $key => $author){
        echo $tab.$tab. ($key+1) ." - ".$author["firstName"]. " ".$author["lastName"]."\n";
    } 

    echo $tab."Article Title: ".$val["data"]["articleTitle"] ."\n";
    echo $tab."Publication Title: ".$val["data"]["pubTitle"] ."\n";
    echo $tab."Key: ".$val["key"]."\n";
}
```

### [run on codepad](http://codepad.org/VnWwtHMl)

and you can use the same method for xml as flowing:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$json_decoded = json_decode($json,TRUE);
//the rest is same
```

for xml you can use the [SimpleXml](http://php.net/book.simplexml)'s functions
or [DOMDocument](http://php.net/class.domdocument) class

---

### Tip

to know the structure of your data that api return to you after it converted to array use `var_dump($your_decoded_json)` in debuging

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to use [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) ?

That would be something like:

```
$entries = json_decode($json, true);
print_r(array_map(function ($entry) {
    return implode(', ', array_map(function ($author) {
        return $author['firstName'];
    }, $entry['data']['authors'])) . ', ' . $entry['data']['articleTitle'] . ', ' . $entry['key'];
}, $entries));
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might be a good start for you:

```
$output = [];

// Loop through each entry
foreach ($data as $row) {
    // Get the "data" block
    $entry = $row['data'];
    // Start your temporary array
    $each = [
        'article title' => $entry['articleTitle'],
        'publication title' => $entry['pubTitle'],
        'key' => $row['key']
    ];
    // Get each author's name
    foreach ($entry['authors'] as $i => $author) {
        $each['author' . ++$i . ' name'] = $author['firstName'] . ' ' . $author['lastName'];
    }
    // Append it to your output array
    $output[] = $each;
}

print_r($output);
```

Example: https://eval.in/369313