# how to access elements in a nested array in php

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

When I run following code:

```
$json2=json_decode($output, true);
echo "<pre>";
echo json_encode($json2, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo "</pre>";
```

I get output as following:

```
[
    {
        "stream": "live\/cm1",
        "size": 1120438999,
        "duration": 16233,
        "periods": 7,
        "path": "\/var\/cache\/nimble\/dvr\/live\/cm1",
        "space_available": 212516282368,
        "vcodec": "avc1.4d001f",
        "resolution": "1280x720",
        "bandwidth": 552176,
        "timeline": [
            {
                "start": 1477757618,
                "duration": 535
            },
            {
                "start": 1477758226,
                "duration": 703
            },
            {
                "start": 1477760431,
                "duration": 14295
            },
            {
                "start": 1477829472,
                "duration": 559
            },
            {
                "start": 1477879433,
                "duration": 40
            },
            {
                "start": 1477881429,
                "duration": 79
            },
            {
                "start": 1477881925,
                "duration": 22
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "stream": "live\/cm10",
        "size": 1790211828,
        "duration": 33976,
        "periods": 23,
        "path": "\/var\/cache\/nimble\/dvr\/live\/cm10",
        "space_available": 212516282368,
        "vcodec": "avc1.4d001f",
        "resolution": "1280x720",
        "bandwidth": 421520,
        "timeline": [
            {
                "start": 1477757606,
                "duration": 193
            },
            {
                "start": 1477757817,
                "duration": 336
            },
            {
                "start": 1477758226,
                "duration": 703
            },
            {
                "start": 1477759027,
                "duration": 1378
            },
            {
                "start": 1477760460,
                "duration": 14273
            },
            {
                "start": 1477829464,
                "duration": 1235
            },
            {
                "start": 1477878029,
                "duration": 469
            },
            {
                "start": 1477882600,
                "duration": 1260
            },
            {
                "start": 1477883914,
                "duration": 208
            },
            {
                "start": 1477911214,
                "duration": 1528
            },
            {
                "start": 1477913185,
                "duration": 185
            },
            {
                "start": 1477913546,
                "duration": 759
            },
            {
                "start": 1477915819,
                "duration": 68
            },
            {
                "start": 1478782219,
                "duration": 69
            },
            {
                "start": 1478782375,
                "duration": 76
            },
            {
                "start": 1478812920,
                "duration": 659
            },
            {
                "start": 1478911726,
                "duration": 2334
            },
            {
                "start": 1478914138,
                "duration": 5
            },
            {
                "start": 1478914233,
                "duration": 2872
            },
            {
                "start": 1478917165,
                "duration": 1133
            },
            {
                "start": 1478976623,
                "duration": 224
            },
            {
                "start": 1478981537,
                "duration": 3658
            },
            {
                "start": 1479065575,
                "duration": 351
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "stream": "live\/cm2",
        "size": 1320002727,
        "duration": 20809,
        "periods": 13,
...........
}]
```

The question I have is how do I access various elements here including how many total sets are there and in each set access a particular object.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Read the `json_decode()` [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) or almost any other question tagged with `json`

Comment: Figured out - this post did the magic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430454/how-to-loop-over-and-access-various-elements-in-an-array-that-is-both-multidimen?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Why are you decoding the output and after that you are encoding it again? Look what json_decode does: http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php

The decoding of your output seems to work well.

So just do the following instead:

```
$json2=json_decode($output, true);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($json2);
echo "</pre>";
```

You will probably get an PHP array containing objects. On this array you can apply anything which is possible with arrays in PHP. You can use `count()` for instance to count the number of results in the array.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

`$json2` is a associative array, access is done using `$json[0]["stream"]` (for example).

To access all elements, try

```
foreach( $json2 as $item ) {
  echo $item["stream"] . " has a size of " . $item["size"] . " bytes";

  foreach( $item["timeline"] as $timeline ) {
    //access the timeline-elements (in the case you actually need those)
    echo $timeline["start"];
  }
}
```

(See also [Parsing JSON object in PHP using json_decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035742/parsing-json-object-in-php-using-json-decode))